# Understanding the Strong Law of Large Numbers and the Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers

I have an issue understanding how the Central Limit Theorem and the Strong Law of Large Numbers coexist. I have constructed the following example, but I cannot find the mistake I made and am therefore asking for your help. Thank you in advance!

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots$ be i. i. d. random variables on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ and $X_1 \in L^2$. Then the Strong Law of Large Numbers tells us that for  $S_n = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} X_k$ we have $\frac{S_n}{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{E} [X_1]$ almost surely. 
But if we consider $P(\frac{S_n}{n} > \mathbb{E}[X_1]) = P(\frac{S_n - n \mathbb{E}[X_1]}{n}>0) = P(\frac{S_n - n \mathbb{E}[X_1]}{\sqrt{nVar(X_1)}} > 0)$ and take the limit we get by the CLT that $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(\frac{S_n - n \mathbb{E}[X_1]}{\sqrt{nVar(X_1)}} > 0) = P(N > 0) = \frac{1}{2}$.
However, since $\frac{S_n}{n}$ converges almost surely to $\mathbb{E}[X_1]$, we have that $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(\frac{S_n}{n} = \mathbb{E}[X_1]) = 1$. Contradicting that the probability above equals $\frac{1}{2}$ since it should be $0$.
Where did I make a mistake?

Also please note that I implicitly assumed that the variance is larger than $0$.

Comment: These do not contradict each other. One of these expressions has $n$ in the denominator and the other has $\sqrt{n}$ in the denominator. You can verify that there is no issue by taking $X_i \sim N(0, 1)$ to be normal, since then the partial sums are also normal so you can compute everything explicitly.

Comment: Your notation $S_n = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0}X_n$ does not make sense. The left-hand-side depends on an index $n$ while the right-hand-side treats $n$ as a dummy variable in the sum. Also, I do not know what $\mathbb{N}_0$ means and I think it would not be hard for you to give that definition.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question accordingly. It was supposed to be the sum from 1 to n.

Comment: The edit needs a minor edit, it should be summing $X_k$ not $X_n$.

Comment: In your third paragraph how do you conclude $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P[S_n/n=0]=1$?

Comment: @Michael Apologies. That should have been the expectation of $X_1$. I concluded that because it converges to $\mathbb{E}[X_1]$ almost surely.

Comment: Got it. Now, let's suppose $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli($p$) where $p=E[X_1]$ is an irrational number in $(0,1)$. Say, $p=1/e$. Now $S_n/n$ is always a rational number so it is impossible for $S_n/n=p$. So $P[S_n/n=E[X_1]]=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for your patience and help. I now understand my mistake.

Comment: Yes, the Law of Large Numbers puts the limit on the other side: $$P\left[\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} S_n/n\right) = E[X_1]\right]=1$$